# jquery and regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I have TextBox on my page. I want to validating this textbox.

The rules are :

1. TextBox should not get more than 20 chars
2. Only aphanumeric and chars like / - # & ^ spaces to be allowed

how to do using jquery in best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate regex would be:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9/#&^\- ]{0,20}$
```

Ask yourself if `A-Z` is the right thing. You may be wanting to allow more than that (accented characters for example).

Use the [JavaScript Unicode Block Range Creator](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block) to accommodate the regex for a broader set of allowed input. Check allowed characters with with the handy [Javascript RegExp Unicode Character Class Tester](http://hamstersoup.com/javascript/regexp_character_class_tester.html).

As always, double check form values on the server side. Relying on JavaScript to do all input checking is dangerous.

For jQuery, have a look at [the Valitator plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator), and use code along the lines of:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
  "yourFormField", 
  function(value) { 
    return /^[a-zA-Z0-9/#&^\- ]{0,20}$/.test(value); 
  }, 
  "Please enter a valid value."
);
```

Comment: Thanku. Is there possible to check validation as user types. Can I do without using plugin, just my own jquery?

Comment: Of course. The plugin was just a suggestion. Use the regex any way you like. However, I would not recommend checking every character as it is typed, but doing a single check when the form field loses focus.

Comment: Plz tell how to do validation without plugin..full example is very good..sorry about it as my first day at jquery

Comment: I want that if user types invalid char and submits form or moves away from textbox, message should fire. How to do. plz give complete example

Comment: No offense, but I would say you try it first, and come back to Stack Overflow with a specific problem you are encountering. "plz give me the codez" doesn't cut it, at least not for me.

Answer (score 0):

^[a-zA-Z0-9/#&^- ]{0,20}$